# PHP mysqli detect number of rows deleted

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a script which allows users to delete rows from a table using php mysqli. I want to make sure that row id 1 and 2 can not be deleted.

My code:

```
$delete = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id > 2 and id = ?");
$delete->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
$ex = $delete->execute();

if($ex === false) { echo 'Could not delete row'; }
else { echo 'Row deleted successfully'; }
```

I believe the **if($ex === false)** part will catch if there was an error when trying to execute the query.

At the minute if user tries to delete id 1 or 2 then the successful message is still displayed as the statement must just be returning true as it executed successfully.

Is there a way to detect if no rows were deleted or count the number of rows that were deleted?

Comment: [mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) Returns the total number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last executed statement

Comment: If you know exact ID's then just first check if ID is not `1` or `2` and only then execute deletion

Comment: `echo $x->affected_rows()`

Comment: Perfect, $stmt->affected_rows is exactly what I need. Thanks